# Why does unittest not see these two lists as equal?

Tags: python, unit-testing

So I was just implementing some classical sorting algorithms for practice and came up with this solution for merge sort:

```
def merge_sort(numbers):
'''Sorts a list based on the traditional merge-sort'''

    if len(numbers) <= 1:
        return numbers

    result = []

    mid = len(numbers) // 2

    left = merge_sort(numbers[mid:])
    right = merge_sort(numbers[:mid])

    l_idx = 0
    r_idx = 0

    # compare all numbers in the two lists
    while l_idx < len(left) and r_idx < len(right):
        if left[l_idx] > right[r_idx]:
            result.append(right[r_idx])
            r_idx += 1
        else:
            result.append(left[l_idx])
            l_idx += 1

    # make sure leftover numbers are added to result
    result += left[l_idx:]
    result += right[r_idx:]

    return result
```

And it seems to work, example:

```
>> number_list = [1, 3, 7, 8, 12, 23, 41, 3, 7, 12, 41, 24, 29]
>> sorted(number_list)
[1, 3, 3, 7, 7, 8, 12, 12, 23, 24, 29, 41, 41]
>> merge_sort(number_list)
[1, 3, 3, 7, 7, 8, 12, 12, 23, 24, 29, 41, 41]
```

The output is correct and sorted properly but when I run my unit-test which looks like this:

```
import sorting as s
import unittest
import random
unsorted_list = [random.randint(1, 120) for _ in range(100)]
expected_sorted_list = sorted(unsorted_list)

    def test_mergesort(self):

        merge_sorted_list = s.merge_sort(unsorted_list)
        self.assertEqual(expected_sorted_list, merge_sorted_list)
```

And when I then run:

```
>> python -m unittest test_sorting
AssertionError: Lists differ: [4, 4[42 chars]2, 13, 14, 15, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,[308 chars] 120] != [4, 4[42 chars]2, 13]

First list contains 84 additional elements.
First extra element 16:
14

Diff is 762 characters long. Set self.maxDiff to None to see it.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.002s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Why does my unittest raise an error? Even though I have tested the merge sort function and it seems to sort correctly.

dir structure:

```
/classical-algorithms
    sorting.py
    test_sorting.py
```

Comment: It appears that one of the lists has a lot of extra elements appended. Can you explain how that happens?

Comment: Ran perfectly fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Let your python file which contains the test be `test_sorting.py`.

Then the following works for me:

```
import sorting as s
import unittest
import random
unsorted_list = [random.randint(1, 120) for _ in range(100)]
expected_sorted_list = sorted(unsorted_list)

class tests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_mergesort(self):
        merge_sorted_list = s.merge_sort(unsorted_list)
        self.assertEqual(expected_sorted_list, merge_sorted_list)
```

Running tests:

```
$python -m unittest test_sorting
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Comment: That's my exact setup. With the unittest class being in a different file and importing my sorters. I added my dir structure to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found the error. My old unittest file looked like this:

```
import sorting as s
import unittest
import random

unsorted_list = [random.randint(1, 120) for _ in range(100)]
expected_sorted_list = sorted(unsorted_list)

    def test_bubblesort(self):

        bubble_sorted_list = s.bubble_sort(unsorted_list)
        self.assertEqual(expected_sorted_list, bubble_sorted_list)

    def test_mergesort(self):

        merge_sorted_list = s.merge_sort(unsorted_list)
        self.assertEqual(expected_sorted_list, merge_sorted_list)
```

I was testing my earlier implemented bubble_sort aswell. When I change it to this:

```
import sorting as s
import unittest
import random


class TestSorters(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_bubblesort(self):

        unsorted_list = [random.randint(1, 120) for _ in range(100)]
        expected_sorted_list = sorted(unsorted_list)
        bubble_sorted_list = s.bubble_sort(unsorted_list)
        self.assertEqual(expected_sorted_list, bubble_sorted_list)

    def test_mergesort(self):

        unsorted_list = [random.randint(1, 120) for _ in range(100)]
        expected_sorted_list = sorted(unsorted_list)
        merge_sorted_list = s.merge_sort(unsorted_list)
        self.assertEqual(expected_sorted_list, merge_sorted_list)
```

Everything works. Is this weird?